# SQL Server : order by time portion of Datetime2 timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, sql-order-by, datetime2

I have a table of orders with a `datetime2(7)` column `O_CreatedOn` and I would like to order this recordset by the time portion only of the `O_CreatedOn` column.

The reason for this is that I need to generate a report that shows the most prevalent times of day when orders are taking place.

Due to the way orders have been stored in the table and the volume of orders, I do not want to break the timestamp column `O_CreatedOn` into `O_CreatedOn_Date` and `O_CreatedOn_Time` columns.

I tried ordering the recordset by a converted `O_CreatedOn` but it's still sorting on the full timestamp.

So, this:

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime, O_CreatedOn, 108)
```

did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert to `time`:

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(time, O_CreatedOn)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks, so much for the prompt, spot-on reply!